# How to separate for loop from if

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, if-statement

```
ok = 1
while ok==1:
    sum = 0
    count = 0    
    a = int(input("Ievadiet, cik skaitļu būs virknē: "))
    
    for i in range( 0, a):
        N = int(input("Ievadiet veselu skaitli: "))
        if N%2 == 1:
            count+= 1
            sum += N
        
        if count != 0:
            average = sum / count
            print("Virknes nepāra skaitļu vidējā artimētiskā vērtība ir: ", average)
        else:
            print("Nevar aprēķināt nepāra skaitļu vidējo aritmētisko.")
    ok = int(input(" Vai turpināt (1) vai beigt (0)?"))
```

This program should ask to type how many numbers will be in chain and then calculate the existing between these numbers the arithmetic mean of the odd numbers. How to separate "if count != 0" from "if N%2 == 1" so the programm will stop calculating arithmetic mean of every number but will calculated only when all numbers of the chain will be written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this code and see if that if what you want to reach. I just de-indented the last `if...else` block so no it first gets all the numbers and then shows the mean.

```
ok = 1
while ok == 1:
    sum = 0
    count = 0
    a = int(input("Ievadiet, cik skaitļu būs virknē: "))

    for i in range(0, a):
        N = int(input("Ievadiet veselu skaitli: "))
        if N % 2 == 1:
            count += 1
            sum += N

    if count != 0:
        average = sum / count
        print("Virknes nepāra skaitļu vidējā artimētiskā vērtība ir: ", average)
    else:
        print("Nevar aprēķināt nepāra skaitļu vidējo aritmētisko.")
    ok = int(input(" Vai turpināt (1) vai beigt (0)?"))
```

Have Fun :)

Comment: Its just the same code, but its working, where is the changes, I don't see...

Comment: Yes, it's the same code, but look at the `if count != 0: ... else: print(...)` part and its indentation :) I just moved them back one step. Now `for` loop and `if...else` block indentation are the same but in your code, `if...else` block was nested in the `if` block. Check it again and if you still have questions, let me know.